# Get the current version of the current package in Python

Tags: python, python-3.x, version

I am building a Python library and I have the requirement inside one of the modules to get the current version of this same library and make decisions based on the current version.
Is this possible in Python? What do you think is the best approach?

Comment: https://note.nkmk.me/en/python-package-version/#:~:text=and%20in%20script-,Get%20package%20version%20in%20Python%20script%3A%20__version__%20attribute,the%20__version__%20attribute.&text=The%20__version__%20attribute%20is%20recommended%20by%20PEP%20(Python,and%20many%20packages%20have%20it. using `__version__` on the package after importing it

Comment: Thanks @AndrewRyan. This option will work if I referenced the library as a package in another project. This is not what I am trying to do. What I am trying to achieve here is; within the same library (let's call it X) containing the current piece of code, I want to get the current version of that library (current version of X).

Comment: so then if you are making a module yourself why not reference the config.toml?

Answer (score 0):

You should use `dir(package)` to see all the possible options for that package. If there is `__version__`, you can use that.

Answer (score 0):

I found that the version of my library is being pulled from Github upon every release by `setuptools_scm`. The developers of `setuptools_scm` provide some tips on retrieving package version at runtime:

https://github.com/pypa/setuptools_scm#retrieving-package-version-at-runtime

Looks like using `importlib.metadata` is the way to go.